# Что это за иконка?

Tags: windows, иконки

При запуске windows через 15 минут на панели появляется и сразу исчезает эта иконка (т.е. запускается и сразу закрывается приложение).

[image: иконка_приложения]

По гугл картинкам искал, в автозагрузку смотрел, весь список приложений пролистал - не могу определить, что это за приложение.

P.S. Извиняюсь, если подобные вопросы здесь неуместны, но не на mailru же спрашивать))

Comment: Странно вы конечно [ищете](https://yandex.ru/images/search?rpt=imageview&url=https%3A%2F%2Favatars.mds.yandex.net%2Fget-images-cbir%2F4867566%2Frog97jX9SRd9bLvSRQvaxQ0134%2Forig&cbir_id=4867566%2Frog97jX9SRd9bLvSRQvaxQ0134). Ну а так вы правы, такое не формат для SO!

Comment: я бы полез в реестр и посмотрел автозагрузку, раз уж спросили)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в данном случае алгоритмы яндекса отработали лучше, чем гугла. Спасибо большое. Просто яндексом принципиально не пользуюсь и в голове даже не было варианта погуглить там))